# Sales Cloud Certification sample implementation assigment

Tags: sales-cloud, certification

Can we get sample assignment(without solution) which covers most(if possible all) areas of sales cloud implementation? The ideal assignment will be the one which is derived from more than one real implementations.

Idea is to gain experience through implementing assignments for those who do not have real implementation experience.

Comment: Hey Ganesh, this site is really for more specific questions with definite answers... there's been a bit of discussion about this one as it is potentially useful but the overall feeling is that it's too general so I'm going to close it.

Comment: That's Ok, close it!

Comment: Thanks for understanding! Hope you find the site useful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [study guide for the exam](http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedSalesCloudConsultant.pdf?v=13) on the [certification page](http://certification.salesforce.com/implementation-experts) it lists particular courses to take in the online training and particular topics.  One of the videos walks through an implementation from the point of view of a Sales Cloud Consultant working at a client.  You could follow that and do all of the analysis on your own and create a functional spec for it.

I am not aware of a workbook like the Force.com Fundamentals book for the Sales Cloud exam.

Comment: yes, the workbook is not available for Sales Cloud though it is available for Service Cloud. I have been through training videos; however I am looking for a comprehensive problem statement which I can actually implement in developer org & thus get firsthand experience of implementation.